# Conditional form states in hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms, 9

I have a node with a field, whose widget uses select boxes and multiple choices are possible. The values are coming from a taxonomy entity reference field. There is another field, a text field, which needs to be hidden.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mijn_condities_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'node_bedrijf_form' || $form_id == 'node_bedrijf_edit_form'){
    $form['field_afstand']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_openbaar_vervoer"]' => array('value' => '236'),
      )
      );
     
  }
}
```

A select box should be added according their choice. For example, when they choose bus or tram, there should be a field to enter the distance in meters. When they choose airport, the range must be in kilometers.

The field isn't hiding.
I already tried to make the field invisible, but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tricky the **Form API #states** works with jQuery selectors if your filed ***field_openbaar_vervoer*** coming from a taxonomy entity reference.
So the input generated HTML will be something like (example from tags fields)

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-tags-3" aria-describedby="edit-field-tags--description" type="checkbox" id="edit-field-tags-3" name="field_tags[3]" value="3" class="form-checkbox">
```

So to target all those inputs you should use [Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in your code and it will work:

```
$form['field_afstand']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name^="field_openbaar_vervoer"]' => ['value' => '236'],
  ],
];
```